# FFmpeg: Get better encoding out of my function

Tags: windows, cmd, ffmpeg, h.264

I needed some assistance on my task.

I am using FFmpeg to burn time and the channel name onto the video.

My goal is to record a stream that is html5 compatible with the following settings:

`Video wrapper MP4`

`Video codec H.264`

`Bitrate 1Mbps`

`Audio codec AAC`

`Audio bitrate 128Kbps`

And `GPU encoding`.

This is what I am using:

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -y -i {udp} -vf "drawtext=fontfile=calibrib.tff:fontsize=25:text='{ChannelName} %{localtime}': x=10: y=10: fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x000000" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 1 -c:v h264_nvenc -r 25 -threads 0  -b:v 1M -profile:v main -minrate 1M -maxrate 1M -bufsize 10M -sc_threshold 0 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -t 00:30:00 {output}\{ChannelName}\{ChannelName}_{year}_{monthno}_{day}__{Hours}_{Minutes}_{Seconds}.mp4`

`{ChannelName}_{year}_{monthno}_{day}__{Hours}_{Minutes}_{Seconds}` are all variable holding information.

`{udp}` holds the UDP stream link.

I have done it this way as I have multiple UDP stream recording.

Although this works, is there a better way for me to do this keeping in the `-vf` as I need the time and channel name.

Currently, this uses between 0.8% to 1.9% GPU on my Quadro P4000. I don't want to use more than this as I have more than 30 streams.

Comment: what are your objectives ( file size , low cpu/gpu usage , bandwidth usage etc) ? what are the video resolutions ? what are the fps of different streams ? what are the compress option?

Comment: currently, file sizes are 250 MB per file in 30 minutes block. However, I have 128 TB of storage and these files get cleaned every 30 days so storage is no issue. The aim is for the CPU and GPU to use less so I can fit more stream onto the server. currently running 20 streams, I am using about 30-40% GPU

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the suggestion

1. -profile:v use Constrained Baseline Profile or Baseline Profile - as most of the Browser or HTML will support.
2. Check How many parallel instances of the Encoder you can run on GPU - Quadro P4000, remaining you can run on cpu.
3. Based on the resolution & fps you can decide the video bitrate of encoding range min & max bitrate. (-b:v 1M -minrate 1M -maxrate 1M) - refer : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Limiting%20the%20output%20bitrate
4. -sc_threshold  (FFmpeg)
   Adjusts the sensitivity of x264's scenecut detection. Rarely needs to be adjusted. Recommended default: 40